# Python won't call the simple test function. But it compiles OK. What's going on?

Tags: python, function

I'm following some classes on Lynda.com to cover some python basics. I'm still new to programming as a whole but have done some projects in C before.

We covered 5 minutes explaining how to call functions. And now we're covering conditionals. No problem right?

This simple function will not print. But compiles OK. Why?

```
def func1():
    x, y = 100, 100

    if (x < y):
        st = "x is less than y"

    elif (x == y):
        st = "x is equal to y"

    else:
        st = "x is greater than y"

    print (st)
    # I have also tried changing this to print(funct1(st)) but still doesn't work.
```

In our last video under 'functions' his examples were:

```
def func1():
  print ("I am a function")

func1()
print (func1())
print (func1)
```

And this works perfectly fine. All 3 print examples and ways to call the function.

If I take the function out and keep the if logic statements and stuff, then it prints. So I don't get what's wrong here. Makes me feel like an idiot.

This is using pycharm IDE and python 3.7, also tried running straight from CMD console. Compiles and runs but does not print anything.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? That isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Oh! May be because you didn't call you func1() in your first example.

Comment: @John Coleman I explained that it will compile fine but won't print the logic (i.e variable 'st')

Comment: I just ran it and it worked fine. Have you tried an online Compiler? You may need to reinstall the Python interpreter.

Comment: @Joseph I commented in a section saying that I tried calling func1 with the syntax "print (func1(st))" as well but it won't print. Also tried print (func1()). Nadda thing.

Comment: @Aspen Dear man, call the function outside the function (for this example). Not inside it. Look the answer given by Jonah Bishop below.

Comment: @Joseph Got it. I should have caught that but coming from C, not having brackets threw me off. Thank you my dude. Sorry for the 20 IQ question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined your function, but you aren't calling it.

```
def func1():
    x, y = 100, 100

    if (x < y):
        st = "x is less than y"

    elif (x == y):
        st = "x is equal to y"

    else:
        st = "x is greater than y"

    print (st)

# Call the function after having defined it
func1()
```

Defining a function merely prepares it to be used in the future. You have to actually call the function to run the function's code.

Comment: yeah.. that was it. Makes sense. and i AM an idiot. I guess I understand why C uses brackets now for scopes haha

Comment: Yes, Python uses white space to delineate blocks, which takes some getting used to when coming from C-style languages.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a function is to reuse code so instead of initializing the x and y variables to a value, you can pass it in as arguments into the function.

```
def func1(x, y):
    if (x < y):
        st = "x is less than y"

    elif (x == y):
        st = "x is equal to y"

    else:
        st = "x is greater than y"

    print (st)

# Call the function after having defined it
func1(100, 100) # Outputs: x is equal to y
# You can use the same code to compare even more values
func1(12, 35) # Outputs: x is less than y
```